# Writing RDF/XML file from rdf Triples in rdflib

Tags: python, rdflib, triples

I have got rdf triples with me, now I am interested in generating RDF/XML file using rdflib in Python. Could you please give me some sample code to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [rdflib docs](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org) could be a good starting point, particularly the [Getting Started](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html) section. For example:

```
import rdflib
from rdflib.Graph import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse("http://www.w3.org/2000/10/rdf-tests/rdfcore/ntriples/test.nt", 
        format="nt")
g.serialize("test.rdf", format="rdf/xml")
```

Answer (score 4):

If **rdf/xml** format is unknown (depends on the version of *rdflib*), use instead:

```
g.serialize("test.rdf", format="pretty-xml")
```